# How can I return two entity objects from web api?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, serialization

What I am trying to do is getting two entity and returning from a single return using Json Object so getting this exception:-

```
Self referencing loop detected for property 'Job' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies
```

Here is what I am doing in code

```
        [Route("api/Listing/GetAllList/{id:Guid}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ResponseWrapper<GenericResponseModel> GetAllList(Guid id)
        {
            
             var heightSafety = database.HeightSafetyForms.Where(j => j.JobId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            var chimneyTower = database.ChimneyTowerForms.Where(j => j.JobId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return ResponseService.ReturnResponse(() =>
            {
                if (heightSafety == null || chimneyTower == null)
                {
                 return new GenericResponseModel(false, "Job could not be found.", null);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new GenericResponseModel(true, string.Empty, Json(new
                    {
                        heightSafety = heightSafety,
                        chimneyTower = chimneyTower
                    }));

                }
            }, Request);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created ModelHelper Class for ChimneyTower and HieghtSafety and assigned the values of the object of ChimneyTower to ChimneyTowerModelHelper object and then returned in the return statement